# Swift: Animate position of a path on a CAShapeLayer

Tags: swift

I have a path and a shape Layer on that I want to draw a line

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: xValue,y: yValue))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: xValue, y: yValue + 300))

// create shape layer for that path

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.strokeColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1).cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
```

But I am also animating the drawing of the line

```
self.chartView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.duration = 0.6
shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")
```

Now to my question:
I also want to animate the position of my path at the meanwhile. So at the moment my line is on the x-Positon of "xValue". I want to move it animated to "xValue - 40.0". I tried it on 2 ways which both didnt work.

1. use UIView.animate. Problem: The x Position is changing but without an animation:

   ```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) {
       var highlightFrame = shapeLayer.frame
       highlightFrame.origin.x = (highlightFrame.origin.x) - 40
       shapeLayer.frame = highlightFrame
   }
   ```
2. add a animation on the shape layer. Nothing happens here

   ```
   let toPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: -40.0, y: 0.0)
   let fromPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
   let movement = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "movement")
   movement.isAdditive = true
   movement.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: fromPoint)
   movement.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: toPoint)
   movement.duration = 0.3
   shapeLayer.add(movement, forKey: "move")
   ```

Anyone has another solution? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
let toPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint(x: -40.0, y: 0.0)
let fromPoint:CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
let movement = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position") // it should be "position"            not "movement"
movement.isAdditive = true
movement.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: fromPoint)
movement.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: toPoint)
movement.duration = 0.3
shapeLayer.add(movement, forKey: "move")
```